# Google maps doesnt work in safari (gray rectangle)

Tags: google-maps, safari, cross-browser

sorry for my bad English.

I dont know why, but google maps API on my website doesnt work in safari browser.. In other browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Opera) its working. Maybe you know what Im doing wrong? There my js code:

locations.tpl :

```
{include file="helpers/menu.tpl"}
<div id="content">
    <div id="my-map"> </div>
</div>
```

maps.js:

```
function init(locations, icon, id){
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(id),{
    zoom: 15,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(25.204120, 55.274700),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    streetViewControl: false,
    panControl: false,
    zoomControlOptions: {position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM}
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    maxWidth: 170
  });
  var markers = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map,
      icon: icon
    });
    markers.push(marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      };
    })(marker, i));
  }
  autoCenter();
  function autoCenter() {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){bounds.extend(markers[i].position);}
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
}
```

index.tpl :

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=en"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$config.views_url}js/maps.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var locations = {$locations};
      var icon = "{$config.views_url}images/icon2.png";    //icon.png
      //locations, icon, html id
      init(locations, icon, 'my-map');

    });
</script>
```

locations.class.tpl :

```
<?php

class locations extends controller {

    function locations() {
        parent::controller("locations");

        $this->fields = array(
            "created" => "created",
            "location" => "string",
            "coordx" => "string",
            "coordy" => "string",
            "descript" => "string",
        );

        //$this->createTableStructure();
    }

    function getLocations(){
        global $coreSQL;
        $location = $coreSQL->queryValue('SELECT CONCAT("[", GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("[`",descript,"`"), CONCAT(",`",coordx,"`"), CONCAT(",`",coordy), "`]"),"]") AS locations FROM locations');
        return $location;
    }
}

?>
```

default.css :

```
#content{
        margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
        width:1280px;
    height:1775px;
    background-image: url(../images/sand.png), url(../images/bg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
        background-position: 0 100%, 50% 50%;   
}

#my-map{
        border:10px solid white;
        width: 800px;
        height: 600px;
        background-color: #CCC;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-top:50px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.46);
      }
```

Comment: I think that there is a problem with JSON on Safari, or maybe I call a function wrongly, that Safari doesnt support? Anyone know. Web page: www.ledai.ae/locations

Answer (score 0):

Ohh I find the answer. I dont know why but Safari give me an error on ` simbol...so i change in locations.class.tpl all there simbols by /'   and everything now working.